# how to get a php script to run a .cpp file

Tags: php, c++, web, wamp

i am trying to find a way to have a PHP script execute a .cpp file, and then return the results via PHP.

I will map out my methodology to avoid confusion in my question:

Certain action on webpage (Button click) -> PHP runs .cpp file -> the results of the .cpp file are returned to PHP -> returned data is used to repopulate the page .

Is this possible to do? (please do not vote down, i have looked online and could not find a solid lead to help me establish this connection)

Comment: Do you know what a `.cpp` file is?

Comment: You can't "run" a C++ source code file. C++ is no interpreted language. You can run a compiled program though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you mean to run a built executable...

The `exec` function will run the application similar to running it through a command line.  This means that you can get the standard output of the application like you would through the command line.

[How to run abc.exe using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251634/how-to-run-abc-exe-using-php)

It's kind of kludgy, if you can, just duplicate the executables functionality in PHP.

Comment: Thank you, i believe this is what i will need to use the .cpp file, using `exec('abc.exe', $output")`. Quick question, assuming i am using c++, would the $output variable be populated with strings from the `std::cout << x <<`?

Comment: Yes sir.  Pass `$output` in by reference, with the `&`.