# Linking a Website to a Console Application in C#

Tags: c#, web

I just wanted some general information about some technologies that would allow me to link a website to a console application in C#.
Let's say for example that users on my website fill a textfield with some information, then I want to take this information, process it into my Console Application, and print some results.

What's the technology to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: take a look at CGI for example

Comment: seems to be what i'm looking for, thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251634/how-to-run-abc-exe-using-php maybe of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the class System.Diagnostics.Process (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.100).aspx) to start your console application.
Then, you can read/write to/from StandardOutput, StandardError and StandardInput, which are normal Streams.