# Execute .exe file on server

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have .exe java file and .html file. Both of them in the same folder on a server. I need to execute the .exe java file by clicking on a button in the html page. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run abc.exe using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251634/how-to-run-abc-exe-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to run the Java code within a HTML page, then please use [Applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet).

Also note that Applet's require the end-user to have the Java plugin installed in their web browser. (It won't work on mobile).