# run exe file on apache server

Tags: php, apache, exe

Should it be possible to put an exe file on an apache server, send a text file via a php form, have the exe process the text file and then send the results back to the client?

Or is this generally not possible (if so, why)?

I looked around a bit but I havent really gotten a conclusive answer. Some say you should use the exe as a cgi script and some say it's only possible on a windows server.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
echo exec("my.exe");
echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Works locally. Should this also work on an apache server hosted by a webspace company? (provided that they didn't prohibit exec).

Comment: Have you tried calling the .exe from your php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251634/how-to-run-abc-exe-using-php

Comment: Ah okay, so it should work if a) the apache server is on a Windows machine and b) the hosting provider allows it? But it is wrong to say that an apache server generally cannot execute an exe file called by php?

Comment: On which OS is apache installed?

Comment: .exe is an executable filefor Windows. Most servers run on *nix flavors, so while it may work on your windows machine it probably will not work live unless you're sure the live server is Windows.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito In my case on windows. However, We are having an argument here. I say "apache server + windows OS" should work, and the other guy says "no, you need an IIS".

Comment: @Pamblam unless you've wine installed ;)

Comment: The host has to allow it, PHP/Apache needs permission to access and execute the file. IIS is for ASP not PHP and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: above this code working in local environment in your PC because in my side it does not run .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is this generally not possible (if so, why)?

There's no "*generally*", it depends on how apache is configured by your host provider. If you've a `vps` or a `dedicated server` the *"generally"* is what you want.

---

Some points to consider:

1. *Play safe* and provide the **full path** to the `exe`, i.e.:

   exec("c:/someDir/my.exe");
2. Make **sure** the user that apache's running under has **permissions** to
   **execute** the file;
3. As you may already know, `exe` files run on windows systems, but **not
   exclusively**, they can run under Linux if you've [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) installed;
4. Consider using `shell_exec` instead of `exec`, why? `shell_exec` returns
   **all of the output stream as a string**. `exec` returns the **last line**
   of the output by default, but can provide all output as an array
   specified as the second parameter;